# What is the benefit of this pattern: loos augmentation

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have the need for a singleton. It really is a rather large "do something" object. Processes information etc.. it could be extended, and some methods could or might even be inherited, but overall, there doesn't need to exist more than one of them. So, I read a bit here which I love the concept: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

I am thinking more in terms of leveraging the sub module behavior.

But, I'd like to break my obj into sub-modules. But I am not seeing the need to pass in the parent sub-module as the "return" on that parent gives me access anyways. ala. Perhaps I am missing the "robustness" or real usage here.

For example.

```
var a = {};

a.m = function(){

    var conf = {
        a: 'aaa',
        b: 'bbb'
    }

    var funcs = {
        func1: function(){
            console.log('a.m sub object func1');
        }

    }
    return {  // doing this gives me access
       conf: conf,
       funcs: funcs
    };
}()

// this sub module obj WILL need some behaviors/methods/vals in a.m
a.anothersub = (function(m){

   var anotherSub = m;
   anotherSub.funcs.func1(); // access to a.m methods do I even need to pass it in?
   a.m.funcs.func1();  // also access to a.m methods

}( a.m || {}))

// is a better approach to extend a.anothersub with a.m? 
// jQuery.extend(a.anothersub, a.m);
```

If both "m" and "anothersub" are part of object 'a'. Is there a need for loose or tight augmentation here and for sake of keeping code compartmentalized and of same function behavior, I am creating these "sub objects".

I read that article and felt I could leverage its power. But not really sure this is the best approach here, or even needed. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all comes down to how tightly-coupled your modules/submodules actually are, and how much you can expect them to exist in all places around your application (ie: every page of a site, or at the global level of an application, et cetera).

It's also broaching a couple of different topics.
The first might be the separation of concerns, and another might be dependency-inversion, while another, tied to both, might be code organization/distribution.

Also, it depends on how cohesive two submodules might be...

If you had something like:

```
game.playerFactory = (function () {
    return {
        makePlayer : function () { /*...*/ }
    };
}());

game.playerManager = (function (factory) { return {/*...*/}; }(game.playerFactory));
```

It might make sense to have the factory passed into the manager as an argument.
At that point, attaching both to `game` is really just a convenient place to make both accessible to the global scope.

Calling `game` from inside of one or the other, however, is problematic, in large systems, systems with lots of submodules, or systems where the interface is still in flux (when are they not?).

```
// input-manager.js
game.inputManager = (function () {
    var jumpKey = game.playerManager.players.player1.inputConfig.jump;
}());
```

If all of your buttons are mapped out and bound to in that way, for every button for every player, then all of a sudden you've got 40 lines of code that are very tightly bound to:

1. The global name of `game`
2. The module name of `playerManager`
3. The module-interface for `playerManager` (`playerManager.players.player1`)
4. The module-interface for `player` (`player.inputConfig.jump`)

If any one of those things changes, then the whole submodule breaks.
The only one the input-manager should actually care about is the object that has the `.inputConfig` interface.
In this case, that's a `player` object...  ...in another case, it might be completely decoupled or stuck on another interface.
You might be half-way through implementing one gigantic module, and realize that it should be six smaller ones.

If you've been passing in your objects, then you really only need to change what you're passing in:

```
game.inputManager = (function (hasInput) {
    var jumpKey = hasInput.inputConfig.jump;
}(game.playerManager.players.player1));
```

Can easily become

```
game.inputManager = function (hasInput) {
    /*...*/
}(game.playerManager.getPlayer("BobTheFantastic").config));
```

and only one line of code changed, rather than every line referencing `game. ......`

The same can be said for the actual global-reference:

```
// my-awesome-game.js
(function (ns, root) {
    root[ns] = { };
}( "MyAwesomeGame", window ));

// player-factory.js
(function (ns, root) {
    root[ns] = {
        make : function () { /*...*/ }
    };
}("playerFactory", MyAwesomeGame));

// player-manager.js
(function (ns, root, player) {
    var manager = {
        players : [],
        addPlayer : function () { manager.players.push(player.make()); }
    };
}("playerManager", MyAwesomeGame, MyAwesomeGame.playerManager));
```

Your code isn't impervious to change, but what you *have* done is minimize the amount of change that any one submodule needs to make, based on external changes.

This applies directly to augmentation, as well.

If you need to override some piece of some software, in a completely different file, 20,000 lines of code down the page, you don't want to have to suffer the same fate as changing interfaces elsewhere...

```
(function (override, character) {
    override.jump = character.die;
}( MyAwesomeGame.playerManager.get(0), MyAwesomeGame.playerManager.get(1) ));
```

Now, every time player 1 tries to jump, player 2 dies.
Fantastic.

If the interface for the game changes in the future, only the actual external call has to change, for everything to keep working.
Even better.

Comment: Thanks Norquard -- the idea is that the inital module 'a.m', that holds alot of the nuts n' bolts. I plan on having a few sub modules... ala.. a.doesthis, a.doesthat etc... and these are more like singular helper items. So, I was trying to figure the best course of action to be able to use them, and have them call methods into the "main sub", "a.m" does that make sense?

Comment: @jamesemanon It does. The pattern doesn't really change.  What you should ask is whether your little packages belong on `a.m` as children, or as siblings of `a.m` with `a.m` injected into their modules for DI purposes, or whether these code blocks even need to be publically accessible at all.  If they're siblings, then attach to the root/et cetera.  If you're attaching submodules to `a.m` then when you import `function(mod) { mod.sub = { }; }(a.m)` and if they just need to initialize, call whatever you need, then return.